# Can't click to move cursor or highlight text inside of Material UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I'm using a Material UI `TextField` component in my React project. I am unable to highlight text or click to move the cursor inside of it.

```
<TextField
  variant={"standard"}
  className={styles._input}
  multiline={true}
  fullWidth={true}
  onChange={ onChange }
  value={ spec.t }
  autoFocus={true}
  onFocus={event => {
    event.target.select()
  }}
  onClick={() => console.log(">>>> CLICKED TEXT INPUT")}
  placeholder={"Enter Text"}
/>
```

The `_input` class simply sets the font of the `TextField`.

The `onClick` event handler I've attached is definitely firing every time I click or drag inside of it, so this isn't an issue with the `z-index` not being set high enough. I also don't have any `user-select: none` in the CSS in my project.

Are there any other things I should look out for that may be causing this? I'm really stumped as to why this is happening. It only happens for this one `TextField`; other `TextFields` in my project work as expected.

Comment: I copy/pasted your text field, minus the class name and using a basic string state and it works just fine. I assumed you tried it without the `className` and it still doesn't work. If you inspect the element are there any erroneous CSS properties? Are there any other props you're passing you didn't include?

Comment: I sifted through the DOM tree and don't see anything that stands out to me. I'm also not passing any other props, the only state that matters is the spec.t. Are there any CSS properties you're aware of that can cause this issue other than z-index and user-select?

Comment: `pointer-events`, but IIUC in that case you should not see the text logged to your console